# How to list Google Scheduler Jobs from all locations within a project with Python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

I want to list all the Google Cloud Schedule jobs within a project, but to use the `ListJobsRequest()` class the parent parameter is required: `projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION_ID`. Since I have jobs in different locations I would like to list all jobs, is it possible to do?

I already tried `projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/*` and `projects/PROJECT_ID/locations`.

In both cases I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\TI\GCP\bq-to-scheduler\main.py", line 97, in <module>
    list_scheduler_jobs()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\TI\GCP\bq-to-scheduler\main.py", line 51, in list_scheduler_jobs
    page_result = client.list_jobs(request=request)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\TI\GCP\bq-to-scheduler\venv\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\scheduler_v1\services\cloud_scheduler\client.py", line 548, in list_jobs
    response = rpc(
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\TI\GCP\bq-to-scheduler\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py", line 154, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\TI\GCP\bq-to-scheduler\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 283, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\TI\GCP\bq-to-scheduler\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 190, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\TI\GCP\bq-to-scheduler\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 52, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission "cloudscheduler.jobs.list" for the resource "projects/projeto1-358102/locations/*" (or the resource may not exist).
```

Help?

Comment: You will need to query each region (LOCATION_ID). The LOCATION_ID looks like `us-east1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list all your available locations in your project using the code below. I also included calling [list_jobs()](https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudscheduler/latest/scheduler_v1/cloud_scheduler.html#google.cloud.scheduler_v1.services.cloud_scheduler.CloudSchedulerClient.list_jobs) to send a request to list the available jobs on the location.

I got the code on listing location in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations/list) but I edited the authentication to use `google.auth` library instead of `oauth2client.client` since this is already deprecated.

```py
from googleapiclient import discovery
import google.auth
from google.cloud import scheduler_v1

def get_project_locations():
    credentials, project = google.auth.default(scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

    service = discovery.build('cloudscheduler', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

    name = f'projects/{project}'
    loc_arr = []
    request = service.projects().locations().list(name=name)
    while True:
        response = request.execute()

        for location in response.get('locations', []):
            loc_arr.append(location['labels']['cloud.googleapis.com/region'])

        request = service.projects().locations().list_next(previous_request=request, previous_response=response)
        if request is None:
            break

    return project,loc_arr

def list_jobs(project_id,location_list):
    client = scheduler_v1.CloudSchedulerClient()

    for location in location_list:
        request = scheduler_v1.ListJobsRequest(parent = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}")

        page_result = client.list_jobs(request=request)
        for response in page_result:
            print(response.name)
            print(response.http_target)
            print(response.schedule)

project_id,location_list = get_project_locations()
list_jobs(project_id,location_list)
```

Output:

[image]

From GCP scheduler:

[image]