# List/Delete Google Cloud Scheduler jobs by prefix

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

Every user on our website can schedule multiple jobs on GCP using an API. The jobs are called `projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION_ID/jobs/USER_ID-RANDOM_STRING`.

Now I need to delete all jobs of a user. Assuming there are many jobs (100k+), how do I delete all jobs of that user? Simply iterating through them does not scale. Any ideas? I'd rather avoid having to store all of the job IDs separately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list Google Scheduler Jobs from all locations within a project with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73264479/how-to-list-google-scheduler-jobs-from-all-locations-within-a-project-with-pytho)

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB Sadly not because I'd have to go through all jobs one by one still. O(n). Looking for a O(log n) at least.

Comment: You can't do a batch request because Scheduler doesn't offer this so yes, the best is to iterate over all the jobs and in any case make concurrent calls to speed up the process and considering to not go over the quotas.